# Vi move through DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, wpfdatagrid, vi

I'm using a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) to display a bunch of data. I have `SelectionMode="Extended"` and `SelectionUnit="FullRow"`.

What I would like to be able to do is to press `J` to move the focus down in the grid, press `K` to move up in the grid, and press `x` to add/remove the focused row to/from the list of `SelectedItems`(basically just like gmail with keyboard shortcuts on)

I'm pretty handy with wpf, but I have yet to be able to accomplish this. I'm not sure that the row focus is separate from the selected items, but I figure what the hell, maybe someone here has done something similar.

Here's what I've tried so far

```
case Key.X:
{
    resultsGrid.SelectedItems.Add(resultsGrid.SelectedItem);
    e.Handled = true;
    break;
}
case Key.J:
{
    //down
    var currow = (DataGridRow) resultsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(resultsGrid.SelectedItem);
    currow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
    //if (resultsGrid.SelectedIndex + 1 >= resultsGrid.Items.Count)
    //    resultsGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //else
    //    resultsGrid.SelectedIndex++;
    break;
}
case Key.K:
{
    //up
    var currow =
        (DataGridRow) resultsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(resultsGrid.SelectedItem);
    currow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up));
    //if (resultsGrid.SelectedIndex - 1 <= 0)
    //    resultsGrid.SelectedIndex = resultsGrid.Items.Count - 1;
    //else
    //    resultsGrid.SelectedIndex--;
    break;
}
```

Currently the current row doesn't move up or down. I've also tried `FocusNavigationDirection.Previous` and `Next` and those don't move the focus either. If I go by index it moves, but pressing X doesn't add to the list of selected items. It seems multi select doesn't want to kick in until you use shift and up/down or shift mouse click

## edit

Ok so I've figured out how to navigate using the `j` and `k` key, but selecting still isn't working. If I move up or down it clears the selection, also pressing `x` doesn't do anything, visually at least.

```
case Key.X:
    resultsGrid.SelectedItems.Add(resultsGrid.SelectedItem);
    e.Handled = true;
    break;
case Key.J:
    {
        //down
        InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Down)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
        });
        resultsGrid.ScrollIntoView(resultsGrid.SelectedItem);
        e.Handled = true;
        break;
    }
case Key.K:
    {
        //up
        InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Up)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
        });
        resultsGrid.ScrollIntoView(resultsGrid.SelectedItem);
        e.Handled = true;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: `Here's what I've tried so far` - Nice. What problems do you have with your current approach?

Comment: Yeah, so the current row doesn't move up or down. I've also tried FocusNavigationDirection.Previous and Next and those don't work. If I go by index they move, but pressing X doesn't add to the list of selected items. It seems multi select doesn't want to kick in until you use shift and up/down or shift mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly - you have a focus and selection per row. You want to move focus via k/j keys and to toggle selection via x key.

I like to use behaviors in these situations - it requires reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll from blen SDK but it also makes for a cleaner and modular code.

[**edit:** this is a quick POC that I did. It will probably require some more null reference protection and handling of fringe/edge cases]

The behavior is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace GridNavigationTest
{
    public class GridNavigationBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
    {
        #region Overrides of Behavior
        /// <summary>
        /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObject_KeyDown;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the behavior is being detached from its AssociatedObject, but before it has actually occurred.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Override this to unhook functionality from the AssociatedObject.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= AssociatedObject_KeyDown;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event handlers
        void AssociatedObject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.J:
                    NavigateGridFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Up);
                    break;
                case Key.K:
                    NavigateGridFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
                    break;
                case Key.X:
                    ToggleRowSelection();
                    break;
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private void ToggleRowSelection()
        {
            var currentlyFocusedRow = FindCurrentlyFocusedRow();
            if (currentlyFocusedRow == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var generator = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator;
            var rowItem = generator.ItemFromContainer(currentlyFocusedRow);
            if (AssociatedObject.SelectionMode == DataGridSelectionMode.Extended)
            {
                if (AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Contains(rowItem))
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(rowItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(rowItem);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = AssociatedObject.SelectedItem == rowItem ? null : rowItem;
            }
        }

        private void NavigateGridFocus(FocusNavigationDirection direction)
        {
            var currentlyFocusedRow = FindCurrentlyFocusedRow();
            if (currentlyFocusedRow == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var traversalRequest = new TraversalRequest(direction);
            var currentlyFocusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
            if (currentlyFocusedElement != null) currentlyFocusedElement.MoveFocus(traversalRequest);
        }

        private DataGridRow FindCurrentlyFocusedRow()
        {
            var generator = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator;
            if (generator.Status != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                return null;
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < generator.Items.Count - 1; index++)
            {
                var row = generator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;
                if (row != null && row.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                {
                    return row;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
<Window x:Class="GridNavigationTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:gridNavigationTest="clr-namespace:GridNavigationTest"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type gridNavigationTest:MainWindow}}, Path=People}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <gridNavigationTest:GridNavigationBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <!--This is here just for testing of focus movement-->
            <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="HotPink" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This requires that one of the rows would have `IsKeyboardFocuedWithin` set to true. You can bake the logic for initial selection into the behavior (or, in a new behavior).

Comment: I'll give this a shot in a few hours, crossin my fingers, this seems like a really nice solution.

Comment: Well I think you win here. Works great. After playing with it though I realized that the selection stuff probably isn't right for what I'm trying to do(I mean it works, but for my application the idea to multiselect like that wasn't a good one). The movement stuff is great though.

Comment: Also, I think you'd be able to accomplish the same feat without having to bring behaviors on board now that I think about it. It's still a nice solution though.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. The reason to use behavior is that I can apply it to any `DataGrid` in any project now (I've been a bit selfish :)). If you don't want to use behaviors, it's easy to translate the code to be used in code-behind of a user control - `OnAttached` and `OnDetaching` are translated to `Loaded` and `Unloading` event handlers; `AssociatedObject` translates to the name of the grid in xaml (`x:Name`).